# Is it possible to remove embed value?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, field, embed

I have been trying to remobe the value of an embed because I don't like it there but I cant find a way to "bypass" it.

Does anyone have a solution?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQxrG.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\u200b`, this is a white space like a space bar, but as a unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

Put a whitespace character, like `\u0020`

Comment: It still says "In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required"